# RNCryptor iOS/PHP and special characters

Tags: php, ios, rncryptor

I'm using RNCryptor to encrypt a message in iOS and then decrypting it in PHP.  However, special characters dissapear from the decrypted string.

How I encrypt in iOS

```
-(NSData *)encryptThis:(NSString *)str
```

{

```
NSString *key = @"mysuper32bitkey";
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data
                                    withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                        password:key
                                           error:&error];

return encryptedData;
```

}

How I decrypt in PHP

```
$b64_data = $message;
$password = "mysuper32bitkey"
// back to binary
$bin_data = $message;// message already in binary. No need for -> mb_convert_encoding($b64_data, "UTF-8", "BASE64");
// extract salt
$salt = substr($bin_data, 2, 8);
// extract HMAC salt
$hmac_salt = substr($bin_data, 10, 8);
// extract IV
$iv = substr($bin_data, 18, 16);
// extract data
$data = substr($bin_data, 34, strlen($bin_data) - 34 - 32);
// extract HMAC
$hmac = substr($bin_data, strlen($bin_data) - 32);

// make HMAC key
$hmac_key = pbkdf2('SHA1', $password, $hmac_salt, 10000, 32, true);
// make HMAC hash
$hmac_hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $data , $hmac_key, true);
// check if HMAC hash matches HMAC
if($hmac_hash != $hmac)
    echo "false";

// make data key
$key = pbkdf2('SHA1', $password, $salt, 10000, 32, true);
// decrypt
$ret = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo trim(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/u', '', $ret));
```

The thing is that if I encrypt "Agresión" in iOS, PHP only returns "Agresin".  Why it doesn't decrypt the "ó" ?  I thought *dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding* would keep special characters... Am I supposed to use another type of encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're stripping the ó (U+00F3) in this line:

```
echo trim(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/u', '', $ret));
```

Note that you're removing all of \x80-\xFF. Don't do that.

Comment: so it should be: echo trim(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F/u','',$ret));   ? Removing the \x80-\xFF

Comment: Why are your stripping any characters here?

Comment: It was from an example without comments. I realize now I was removing a lot of unicode characters.

Comment: I happen to know the code you were copying. The original author was ignoring the HMAC. What he did was treat the HMAC as if it were ciphertext and just decrypted it. He then assumed that none of the HMAC would decrypt into ASCII characters (not a great bet), so he stripped any non-ASCII in the final string. The correct solution is to extract and validate the HMAC as you're doing.